# When are changes in Synchronized block visible to other threads

Tags: java, synchronization

Say that I update values of two variables in a synchronized method. Would it be possible that the new values set in synchronized method be visible to other threads **before** exiting the synchronized block?

```
public synchronized void setValues(){
    a=5;
    // assume thread is preempted after this assignment
    // would the value 5 be visible to other threads?
    // my understanding is that the values will not be flushed to
    // main memory until the lock is released- i.e., until the synchronized
    // method is complete. So the changes will not be visible to other 
    // threads even when not using synchronization
    b=10;
}
```

Below method is **not** synchronized, so I understand that the thread **may**   see stale values. My question is if the thread is preempted after assignment to a, is it ever possible that the new value "5" for variable a be visible in printValues method?

```
public void printValues() {
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, changes made within synchronized *can* (but aren't guaranteed) to be visible before you get to the end of the synchronized block. Basically, you usually need to synchronize (on the same lock) when reading *or* writing data in order to get a consistent view of the world.

The guarantees provided for synchronization are to make "doing the right thing" (synchronizing appropriately) work correctly - they *don't* guarantee that changes are made atomically when you're *not* doing the right thing (observing the shared variables without synchronizing).

You can (to some extent) think of the writes within the synchronized block as being like calls to `OutputStream.write()` with the exit of the synchronized block being like a `flush()` call. When you're half way through the block, some of the data you've written *may* have made it to the output file (or whatever) - but it might still be buffered. That's not meant to be an indication of how the memory model is implemented, just an analogy to help you understand how the visibility isn't guaranteed.

Comment: However synchronized guarantees that a and b are written to the "main memory" at the end of the synchronized block.

Comment: Your analogy is great! Could you please point me out to the specification in Java memory model that addresses this part if you know?

Comment: @lexicore: No, it doesn't guarantee that. The memory model isn't written in terms of "when writes to main memory occur" - it's written in terms of "happens-before" and "synchronized-with" relations.

Comment: @Satish: Basically the whole of section 17.4 of the JLS: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4In particular, "Informally, a read r is allowed to see the result of a write w if there is no happens-before ordering to prevent that read." In your case there's no happens-before to prevent `printValues` from seeing the "new" value of `a`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - thanks much! Your comment was just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, it is the formalization used in JLS. I'd like to clarify, maybe I misunderstood something. Assume a was 0 , b was 0 (a and b are not volatile) and thread 1 executed setValues(). Is it possible for thread 2 to see b = 0 after thread 1 has finished executing setValues() and performed the unlock action?

Comment: @lexicore: If it doesn't lock, then I believe there'll be no happens-before, so yes, it could.

Answer (score 1):

The `synchronized` doesn't guarantee that value of `a` will be flushed immediately. It will be if `a` is volatile.